# Query composite index with Hibernate for many entities

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, composite-key

I am using Hibernate and want to query multiple entities using a composite index (a,b,c,d). The SQL statement could look like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE a = 2 AND b = '2001' AND c = 'xx' AND d = 23
OR a = 2 AND b = '2002' AND c = 'xx' AND d = 23
-- OR ...
;
```

Is there a chance to pass hibernate just a list for such a query? What I don't want is to use a StringBuffer to concatenate a statement depending on the length of my list.

Comment: you should use ditached crieteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criterai it´s the best for this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/)

I hope help you